# Order of CSS selectors

Tags: css, selector

Take a look at this example, simple enough:

http://jsfiddle.net/8YuKb/

Now look at this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/n223Z/1/

The ONLY difference between the two is the line

```
.text_left { text-align:left; }
```

is moved above the following line:

```
.title {
margin:4px;padding:6px;
background-color:black;color:white;
font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
}
```

... and now the CSS does not work??? (at least not in IE)

Can someone please explain why???

I was under the impression that because the "text_left" selector was last in the list the text in the div should be aligned left (regardless of the order of CSS declarations) -- is that not the case????

I do not understand why it works in one case and not the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, the order of the classes in the HTML has no effect.

Both of the following are the same, as they are merely elements with 2 of the same classes.

```
class="title text_left"
class="text_left title"
```

On the other hand, the order of the elements does matter in CSS, as the stylesheet is read from top to bottom (cascade).

Thus `text-align:left` is being applied on both elements, yet due to the order in which they appear, it is overwritten by `text-align:center`, as it appears below it.

Comment: Yes the order in the DOM has no effect, what I am seeing is that changing the location (order) of the declarations in the CSS file DOES have an effect -- see the difference in the jsfiddle demos.

Comment: @user1377587 Maybe I didn't address that clearly enough in the answer. But the position of the elements in the stylesheet does effect it. It is read from top -> bottom. Thus, both styles are being applied, but one is being overwritten, as it appears later.

Comment: Understood ! -- I was under the impression that class "title" would set the text alignment to center -- then the browswer would see "text_left" which would replace the alignment with left -- but to my horror you are saying only the class seen last in the STYLESHEET declaration is being applied -- correct?

Comment: JoshC - found this -- which pretty much says what you said:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133761/css-and-order-of-styles?rq=1  Thanks!

Comment: @user1377587 Correct, I will clarify that in my answer. It is the order in which they appear in the stylesheet that effects it.

Answer (score 0):

1.in html

```
class="title text_left"
class="text_left title"
```

has the same effect when they apply to the same element: the class sequence they appear in

html attribute has no effect in the final result

2.in css file:

```
.title {}
.text_left {}
```

when the two class apply to a element such as

```
<div class="title text_left"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="text_left title"></div>
```

the html has the same effect(as describe in 1), so the div will apply all rules in .title

and .text_left.  if the same style has declared in both .title and .text_left.  the rule

in .text_left will win (the one declared last in css file win when their selector has the

same specificity)

3.in css file

```
.text_left {}
.title {}
```

when an element has both the two classes, all style rule in the two class  will apply to

the element,  if two attrbute conflict, .title will win

maybe you mixed the word: the one declare last will win

it means: the sequence of css rule declare in source file effect the final result

not: the sequence of attribute declare in html element